# How to calculate the flux of a field by integrating its form over a chain?

Tags: differential-geometry

While reading [Arnold's classical mechanics book](https://books.google.com/books?id=UOQlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA187) I encountered this problem:

[image]

I understand that every 2-form on manifold $M$ corresponds to some field $A$ and vice versa. But I cannot proceed from here and actually calculate the flux.

In addition, Arnold says that the space of 2-forms is isomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^n$ only for $n=3$.

I don't see why it doesn't hold for any $n$, as we can span $\mathbf{R}^n$ by all the valid non-degenerate pairs of ${\{x_i \wedge x_j \}_{i,j}^{n,n}}$

Answer (score 2):

For $U$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $\mathfrak{X}(U)$ denote the space of vector fields on $U$ and let $\Omega^k(U)$ denote the space of $k$-forms on $U$ ($0 \leq k \leq n$). Then, given the standard inner product and orientation on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have the following isomorphisms:

1. $\flat : \mathfrak{X}(U) \to \Omega^1(U)$, $\mathbf{F}^\flat := \sum_{i=1}^n F^i \, dx^i$;
2. $\ast : \Omega^1(U) \to \Omega^{n-1}(U)$, $\ast dx^i := (-1)^{i-1}dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i-1} \wedge dx^{i+1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$;

in terms of which

1. the work done by $\mathbf{F} \in \mathfrak{X}(U)$ along an oriented curve $C$ in $U$ (i.e., an oriented $1$-dimensional submanifold of $U$) is $\int_C \mathbf{F}^\flat$;
2. the flux of $\mathbf{F} \in \mathfrak{X}(U)$ through an oriented hypersurface $\Sigma$ in $U$ (i.e., an oriented $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold of $U$) is $\int_\Sigma \ast \mathbf{F}^\flat$.

So in general, what you actually have is $\mathfrak{X}(U) \cong \Omega^1(U) \cong \Omega^{n-1}(U)$; from this perspective, when $n=3$, you have that $\mathfrak{X}(U) \cong \Omega^1(U) \cong \Omega^2(U)$ precisely because of the "numerological" coincidence that $2 = 3-1$.

Comment: Is $\ast$ supposed to be $\sharp$?

Comment: No. $\sharp : \Omega^1(U) \to \mathfrak{X}(U)$ is the inverse of $\flat : \mathfrak{X}(U) \to \Omega^1(U)$—$\sharp$ and $\flat$ are collectively known as the “musical isomorphisms”—whilst $\ast : \Omega^1(U) \to \Omega^{n-1}(U)$ is a particular case of the Hodge star operator $\Omega^k(U) \to \Omega^{n-k}(U)$.

Comment: Incidentally, while we're at it, it might be worth recording that for $\mathbf{F} \in \mathfrak{X}(U)$, $\operatorname{grad}\mathbf{F} = (d \mathbf{F}^\flat)^\sharp$ whilst $\operatorname{div}\mathbf{F} = \ast d(\ast \mathbf{F}^\flat)$; in the special case where $n=3$ (so that $n-1 = 2 = 1+1$), one also has that $\operatorname{curl}\mathbf{F} = (\ast^{-1} d \mathbf{F}^\flat)^\sharp$. This, then, is why Stokes's theorem for differential forms simultaneously generalises the standard theorems of vector analysis.

Comment: Argh, rather, if $f : C^\infty(U) \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, then $\operatorname{grad} f = (df)^\sharp$.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Thank you for the record of Stoke's theorem and generalized standard vector analysis theorems. +1